# Secondary hard disk drive spins up when copying/pasting large amounts of data

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, ssd, copy-paste

My operating system (Windows 8) is installed on a SDD disk and I have an hard disk drive installed on the computer for storage.

I notice when I am copying and pasting large amounts of data from one Excel sheet to another my storage drive starts to spin up. It seems that the computer is using the secondary hard disk drive to temporarily store the large amount of data before its pasted. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Your paging file may be on the D: drive. It's actually recommended NOT to put the paging file on an SSD.

Comment: There are other reasons why a disk could be woken up from other activities not related to the specific disk, indexing could be occuring for the new file, an AV software wants to check a new file. even asking for any single disk size (my computer) or any single files metadata can get a disk to wake back up. So it does not have to be a temp item, or paging.  Viewing the resource monitor on the DIsk tab should show you , even seconds after, any item on the other disk it had attempted access of. Plus other things, that are not likely for the specified info provided.

Comment: "It seems that the computer is using the secondary hard disk drive to temporarily store the large amount of data before its pasted." How do you know this for sure, or is it an assumption?

Comment: This is an assumption because I notice it starting up when I am copying and pasting the data, Also it seems the data gets pasted slow which leads me to believe the HDD is being used. If the data was being copied on the SSD drive the paste time would be faster.

Comment: Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If this is due to Windows needing to free memory by writing to the page file, you can increase the RAM in your system to help prevent the need for that.